# Replace a char into NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring, str-replace, nsmutablestring

I want simply replace all occourrencies of "+" with a blank " " char...
I tried some sample listed here, also used NSSMutableString, but the program crash...
what's the best way to replace a char from another??
thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to replace with a mutable string (NSMutableString) in-place:

```
[theMutableString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"+"
                                  withString:@" "
                                     options:0
                                       range:NSMakeRange(0, [theMutableString length])]
```

If you want to create a new immutable string (NSString):

```
NSString* newString = [theString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+"
                                                           withString:@" "];
```

Comment: thankyou! it works fine! I don't know yesterday what was the problem.. now is ok!

Comment: Do I have to release the string explicitly later?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *firstString = @"I'm a noob at Objective-C", *finalString;

finalString = [[firstString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"O" withString:@"0"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"o" withString:@"0"];
```

Got the code from [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=500072)!